# Flutter Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to create a bottom navigation bar for a flutter website. I'm getting an error which is mainly having too many positional arguments. The error is coming from my BottomBar class. I get the error when I call the BottomBar constructor. Please may someone kindly assist

```
class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
}
```

I call the constructor BottomBar() then get the error

This is the error:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.
```

Comment: share the code where you are calling the BottomBar constructor and getting the error

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your class!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
}}
```

Comment: But when I call the BottomBar constructor in another class I'm getting the error

Comment: I made a silly mistake I was calling the BottomBar constructor outside the Widget  But at least it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

When you call BottomBar() you are trying to pass a parameter but your BottomBar() class doesn't have any parameter it just have one optional parameter.
So you must call it like:
BottomBar();

And you will be fine.

Comment: When I call BottomBar(); in the other class it gives an error and says it expets the comma and not the semi colon

Comment: When you call it in Widget replace ; with ,
like BottomBar(),

Comment: I had a sily mistake I was calling BottomBar constructor outside the class but it's working now thanks for the help 